# Can't get alert to not show if value is correct

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the following form submission to show alert box if value is not equal to 'Province"

```
 function validate_form ( )
    {

    if ( document.contactForm.Province!='Region 1' )

    alert ( "Please Note: We only install in Region 1!" );

    }
```

My form name is "contactForm" my select menu is called "Province" I always get the alert here regardless of the selection in Province.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are actually looking at the value... try ".value" after Province

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare it to the value of that element:

```
 if ( document.contactForm.Province.value != 'Region 1' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function validate_form ( )
{
    var temp = document.getElementbyId(Province);
    var strUser = temp.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    if (strUser != 'Region 1' )
        alert ( "Please Note: We only install in Region 1!" );
}
```